# File upload api for yii2

Tags: ionic-framework, yii2

I am using Ionic framework for mobile app develop. My question is how set up RestApi for file uploading using Yii2.

This is our normal api:

```
public function actionNew()
{
    $params=$_REQUEST;

    $model = new Apijobseekerprofile();
    $model->attributes=$params;

    if ($model->save()) {
        // $this->setHeader(200);
        echo json_encode(
            array(
                'status' => 1,
                'data' => $model->attributes
            ),
            JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
        );
    } else {
        // $this->setHeader(400);
        echo json_encode(
            array(
                'status' => 0,
                'error_code' => 400,
                'errors' => $model->errors
            ),
            JSON_PRETTY_PRINT
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To receive a file in your API I would use a PUT request (simpler than POST/multipart) and fetch the data from the stream "php://input".

Looking at your "normal API" I don't see that you are using the built in API-support of Yii2. It's quite nice and provide support for authentication, validation, etc. [Have a look here in the Yii2 guide.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html)

Comment: thanks for your reply.i am new in ionic and yii2. I am not under stand your answer .plz post some example code or any useful link.thanks again.

Comment: I believe you need to get further on your own, at least it's out of scope for me. As I see it you have two options. 1) Setting up a Yii2 API following examples in the Yii2 guide (including authentication and other useful REST-stuff).  2) Go for a simpler PHP-solution only for uploading a file. Here is a link on that: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php